# Will hibernate compare locale and string?

Tags: java, hibernate

So I am in the middle of a huge refactoring and unable to start application and test it myself, unfortunately neither I have time to create some small application for this test so I thought that this great community have some experienced people who already did this and I am kindly ask for their help.
My question is: will hibernate be able to compare `String` and `java.util.Locale` using `Restrictions`, eg will this code work?:

```
public SomeClass getOne(String locale){
    return session.createCriteria(SomeClass.class)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("locale", locale)).uniqueResult();
}
```

Where `locale` in arguments is kind of 'en' or 'zh' or any other String that comes from `java.util.Locale.toString()` method , and `SomeClass` is something like:

```
class SomeClass {
    private Locale locale;
    //other stuff
}
```

If mapping is relevant here is it's part about locale:

```
<property name="locale" column="locale" type="java.util.Locale"/>
```

Comment: Locale is a String in your method. For this to work properly, I believe that the restriction value needs to be the actual type of the field you are adding criteria for (i.e. - `Locale`). What does this String argument represent exactly?

Comment: You appear to have dropped a closing parenthesis (`)`).  Perhaps it is supposed to go immediately before `.uniqueResult()`.  Please fix this to clarify your intent.

Comment: It looks like "en", or "zh" or any other locale like the one java will make from Locale's `toString()` method

Comment: From what I can see, you are mapping Java values of type `Locale` to the attribute, and you are forming a `Restriction` that the value of that attribute should be equal to an object of the given type.  This should work.  Hibernate supports locales as one of its basic types.  *How* it does that -- i.e. whether it is actually comparing `String` objects to `Locale` objects or any such thing -- is an implementation detail that should not concern you.